# MySQL 5.7.13 Homebrew on OS X EL Capitan: ERROR! The server quit without updating the PID file on startup

Tags: mysql, sql-server, macos, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

For some reason, when I try to start up the server using the `mysql.server start` command, it gives the following error.

`ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file(/usr/local/var/mysql/hostname.pid)`

I have no idea why this was happening and really don't know what to do about it.  When I try to login to the server (Even though it's not running) with `mysql -u root` which doesn't have a password as of now, it gives me this error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

I'm guessing this is because the server isn't started, but I can't get it started in the first place.

I've tried:

- Creating the PID file `touch /usr/local/var/mysql/hostname.pid`
- `brew update` `brew doctor` and `brew upgrade` before a reinstallation of mysql

But nothing I do seems to work.  Any help would be great.

**Update:**

I checked the error log located in `/usr/local/var/mysql/hostname.err` and gathered this information that may be helpful to solving this problem.  There is a line in that file that states the following.

```
[ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
[ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
[ERROR] Aborting
```

So I guess there's another mysql server running somewhere that I'm not aware of?  How can I shut this down?

I ran `ps -aef | grep mysql` and got the following input.  Excluding the `ps` process.

```
502 34914     1   0 12:17pm ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql
502 35006 34914   0 12:17pm ??         0:00.22 /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.13/bin/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.13 --datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.13/lib/plugin --bind-address=127.0.0.1 --log-error=/usr/local/var/mysql/hostname.err --pid-file=/usr/local/var/mysql/hostname.pid
```

Comment: Although this is an older post.  I'd like to know the reason why this got down voted.  I only want to know what I did wrong so that I won't repeat it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out once I ran the `ps -aef | grep mysql` command.  I had to end all of the mysql processes.  I guess another mysql server was running preventing me from connecting with the port 3306.

I killed the process using `sudo kill -9 <pid>`.